# How to echo text into a specific line and column of a file?

Tags: batch, batch-file

I'm trying to echo text from a batch with `echo text here>file.txt`command but is it possible to echo the text into something like Ln20 Col30 or something like that

i've tryed these without any good result:

```
set wfile=aze.txt
set wcontent=txt here
for /F "skip=20 delims=30" %%p in %wfile% do echo %wcontent%
```

I know that to find a text in a file we can use the `find` command but idk how to write

does anybody now a command that can help with this ?
 I'd be thankful for any feedback

---

i've found i might be able to find the line that i want to rewrite and just rewrite the whole thing, for the moment i found this code

```
@echo off &setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "file=file.txt"
set "lastline=txt here"
    for /f %%i in ('type "%file%"^|find /c /v ""') do set "last=%%i"

<"%file%" >"%file%.tmp~" (

  for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%file%"^|findstr /n "^"') do (


set "line=%%i"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 for /f "delims=:" %%j in ("!line!") do if %%j equ %
 echo(!lastline!
) else (
 echo(!line:*:=!
 )
 )
endlocal
 )
)
move /y "%file%.tmp~" "%file%"
```

the only issue is that this will write the last line, can we select the line ???

Hey T3RROR, a way to maybe store a variable with the output of dir, would be to output the dir command in a temp file and then read that file and put whats read into a variable, and after DEL the file because we don't need it anymore

```
@echo off

rem here, input dir /b file.txt /s into inputfiletxtword.txt

set "txtlist=|type %temp%\inputfiletxtword.txt"
echo %txtlist%
pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*** Update ***

The way you've attempted to set the path does not work.

*** Updated, Set /P for all input***

A Program for substituting a target line for any text file type:

```
@ECHO OFF
TITLE %~dp0
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM - Allow definition of inputfile via drop and drag. Cannot handle Spaces.
::: Set /p "inputfile=Drag and Drop your File ]>"

:select
cls

Set /p inputfile=[Type or paste full filepath, or drop file If no Spaces:]>
IF not defined inputfile goto select
IF NOT exist "%inputfile%" GOTO select

REM - Capture info to rename temp file with later
for %%a in ("%inputfile%") do (
    Set name=%%~na
    Set Location=%%~dpa
    Set EXT=%%~xa
)

Set "TempReplaces=!Location!!name!!EXT!"

REM - Count number of lines in file

Set avail=0
REM - Check available lines:
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (%inputfile%) do (
    set /a avail+=1
)

REM - Select Line Number

:linenumber
cls
ECHO File: %inputfile%
Set /p subline=[File Contains: %avail% Lines. Line Number to Substitute:]

REM - Ensure the linenumber is numerical

Set /a test=%subline%+1
IF %test% LSS 2 GOTO linenumber

REM - Enter Replacement String

Set /p substitution=[Enter Replacement Text:]

REM - Function counts lines then Echoes the defined text when target line is encountered.

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%l in (%inputfile%) do (
    set /a line+=1
    if !line! EQU !subline! (
        echo %substitution% >>%Location%TempSub%EXT%
    ) else (
        echo %%l >>%Location%TempSub%EXT%
    )
)

REM - Replace File With Substitution
DEL /Q "%TempReplaces%"
TIMEOUT 1 > nul
FOR %%n IN ("%Location%TempSub%EXT%") DO (
REN %%n "%name%!EXT!"
)

ECHO Done
TIMEOUT 2 > nul
EXIT
```

Comment: thx allot ^^ gonna try it

Comment: its working really well thx allot ^^

Comment: Your Welcome. If you have any questions about how any of it works, just ask.

Comment: hey T3RROR your program works but only using path to give and not only the file,i have a file1234.txt on desktop and it will not find file, but when i put in the file path, everything will work perfectly

Comment: everything is working really well, thx allot ^^, no problem, my bad

Comment: All well working, Thx allot ^^

Comment: I'll share the full code when i''m finished with everything

Comment: the problems in trying to set the output of Dir to a variable or File.
Can create a file in the line with the Dir command, so my file exist check worked fine, but I failed to test if the output was stored, which for some odd reason isn't.

If you find a way to store the output of Dir that works, let me know.

Comment: I can get Dir to output all paths for files of a given extension, but not a specific file.